# How to use position() in XSLT for looping

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I have an XML like so;

```
<TerminalRoutes>
        <Segment>
            <From>
                <previous>DEN </previous>
                <current>DNV</current>
            </From>
            <From>
                <previous>LAX </previous>
                <current>LAS</current>
            </From>
        </Segment>
        <Segment>
            <To>
                <previous>ATL </previous>
                <current>ATN</current>
            </To>
            <To>
                <previous>JFK</previous>
                <current>LGA </current>
            </To>
        </Segment>
 </TerminalRoutes>
```

I am trying to transform the XML into HTML using XSLT and I am applying this template

```
<xsl:template match="TerminalRoutes">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Terminal Routes</b>
                </td>
                <td>&#160;</td>
                <td>&#160;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            <td>TERMINAL ROUTES FROM</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Segment/From/previous"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Segment/From/current"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>TERMINAL ROUTES TO</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Segment/To/previous"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Segment/To/current"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
```

and the resultant HTML gives me the first result set i.e the first "From" and the first "To".

What I want is to re-apply the same template, so I can capture the second result set i.e the second "From" and the second "To". I believe there is a `position()` function that can be used with  but I am not sure how.

Comment: Note that your code relies on the XSLT 1.0 "feature" that xsl:value-of, given a node-set, ignores all but the first node. It's a good idea not to rely on this, because it changes in XSLT 2.0. If you want the first, use `select="Segment[1]/From/previous"`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as example for how `position()` can be used in a `for-each` loop:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="TerminalRoutes">
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="Segment/From">
<xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Terminal Routes</b>
    </td>
    <td>&#160;</td>
    <td>&#160;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES FROM</td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="previous"></xsl:value-of>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="current"></xsl:value-of>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES TO</td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="//Segment/To[$position]/previous"></xsl:value-of>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="//Segment/To[$position]/current"></xsl:value-of>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Terminal Routes</b></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES FROM</td>
    <td>DEN </td>
    <td>DNV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES TO</td>
    <td>ATL </td>
    <td>ATN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Terminal Routes</b></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES FROM</td>
    <td>LAX </td>
    <td>LAS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TERMINAL ROUTES TO</td>
    <td>JFK</td>
    <td>LGA </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`position()` automatically increments in the for-each loop, so `select="//Segment/To[$position]/previous"` will be `//Segment/To[1]/previous` for the first `Segment/From` and `//Segment/To[2]/previous` for the second one.
For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms256233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"

>

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="TerminalRoutes">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Terminal Routes</b>
      </td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/TerminalRoutes/Segment/From">
    <tr>
      <td>TERMINAL ROUTES FROM</td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./previous"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./current"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TERMINAL ROUTES TO</td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Segment/To[1 + count(preceding-sibling::*)]/previous"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Segment/To[1 + count(preceding-sibling::*)]/current"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`1 + count(preceding-sibling::*)` gives you the index of the current FROM element compared to it's siblings by counting the number preceding it (NB: indexes start at 1 instead of 0 in XML technologies).
We then use this number to specify that we want the `To` element with the same index as the `From` element we're currently matching on.

NB: Despite the above solution working, if possible I'd recommend a better approach: restructure your source XML to better group the data; i.e. put related FROM and TO values under the same parent, so that the data structure implies this relationship, making it simpler to read, validate, and work with.

e.g.

```
<TerminalRoutes>
  <Route>
    <From>
      <previous>DEN </previous>
      <current>DNV</current>
    </From>
    <To>
      <previous>ATL </previous>
      <current>ATN</current>
    </To>
  </Route>
  <Route>
    <From>
      <previous>LAX </previous>
      <current>LAS</current>
    </From>
    <To>
      <previous>JFK</previous>
      <current>LGA </current>
    </To>
  </Route>
</TerminalRoutes>
```

Comment: +1 `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*" />` does not need a `select` attribute, just apply templates to all content. Also, matching `text()` in an empty template is considered a cleaner solution than matching `*`by many, together with `xsl:strip-space`. See http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyZ.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasMüller; I'll amend the above code to reflect your comments later today...